# When can I use lodash.after()?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I'm new to functional programming, and someone recommended [`lodash`](http://lodash.com) for understanding major higher-order functions.

Browsing lodash API docs, I couldn't grasp the [sample code](http://lodash.com/docs#after) for `_.after()`:

```
var saves = ['profile', 'settings'];

var done = _.after(saves.length, function() {
  console.log('Done saving!');
});

_.forEach(saves, function(type) {
  asyncSave({ 'type': type, 'complete': done });
});
// → logs 'Done saving!', after all saves have completed
```

The sample code above didn't implement `asyncSave()`, so I should implement the function for myself. But I have no idea how to implement it. It's because I don't understand the specification of `_.after()` itself.

It'll be great if someone explains the function easier than the API docs says. Or an easy-to-understand and practical example for the function would be a big help. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`_.after` takes as arguments a count `n` and a function `f`, and it returns a new function which we could call `fp` (for "f prime"). The function `fp` is such that it keeps a count of how many times it has been called. As long as the number of times `fp` is called is less than `n`, calling `fp` does nothing (other than keep the count of times it was called). Once the number of times `fp` is called is equal or greater than `n`, `f` is called.

So:

```
var _ = require("lodash");
var fp = _.after(3, function () { console.log("OMG!"); });
fp(); // Nothing
fp(); // Nothing
fp(); // Prints "OMG!"
```

The function `asyncSave` would be something that performs a save operation asynchronously for a given type of data (the `type` field in the object passed to it), and upon finishing the save operation calls a callback (the `complete` field in the object passed to it) exactly once.

So the `_forEach` loop calls `asyncSave` once per item in `saves` meaning that one save operation is launched per item in `saves`. Since `done` is the callback for `asyncSave`, eventually `done` will be called, once per save operation. Because `done` was created with `_.after` and the count passed to `_.after` was equal to `saves.length`, the anonymous function passed to `_.after` won't actually execute until `done` has been called `saves.length` times. In other words, it won't be called until all save operations launched in the example are complete.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Your example is much better to understand than lodash API doc's example.